# send a file using c in an adhoc network

Tags: c, linux, networking

i want to send a file using c in an adhoc network in mt linux platform...plz help me with the header files and functions that i need to use

Comment: Please rephrase your question and subject.

Comment: Is this homework? What have you tried so far? Subject lines like this are likely to get you downvotes here - please use a subject line which briefly states your concrete problem. Also note that we are happy to help you if we see that you did try. But we won't do all the work for you.

Answer (score 2):

You could just use the `system()` call to invoke `scp`, e.g.

`system("scp file.dat user@remote-host:path/to/directory/");`

`$ man system`

`$ man scp`